# Spring transactions with caught Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Recently, I've been working with Spring boot + spring data jpa + hibernate. I faced one problem with spring transactions. Here is my service class and two questions:

```
@Transactional
@Service
class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRep;

    public void method_A() {
       try {
          method_C();

          .....

          method_B();
       } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public void method_B() {
       Entity e = new Entity();
       e.set(...);

       myRep.save(e);
    }

    public void method_C() throws Exception {
       ....
    }
}
```

1.If method `method_C()` throws an Exception and I want to catch it and log it, the transaction is not rollbacked in method `method_B()`, because the Exception does not reach Spring framework.  So how should I do in order to catch Exceptions from `method_C()` and at the same time do not lose capability of method `method_B()` be rollbacked?

2.Consider new method `method_A()`.

```
public void method_A() {
   for(...) {
      ...
      ...
      method_B();
   }
}
```

I want invoke `method_B()` in a loop. If an exception occurs in a `method_B()` I want transaction of `method_B()` be rollbacked but `method_A()` should not exit and the loop should continue excuting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't catch exceptions, spring will log the exception anyway including the full stack trace, so why bother doing it yourself. For option 2 just put a try/catch inside the for loop. Method B still acts as is (including rollback) and method a still continues. If you want some additional exception handling you can always write an after throwing aspect to do the logging, or else add a catch but always rethrow the exception (but due to the already logging of Spring that would be a but redundant).

Comment: if I add `try-catch` block in a loop, transaction is not rollbacked in the `method_B()`. The entity is saved and commited to database.

Comment: The assumption here was that methodA wasn't in a transaction, only method B.

Comment: You mean if write `@Transactional` only before method `method_B()` it should behave like you've said?

Comment: Well no as that would be an internal method call and because Spring, by default, uses proxies there would be no transaction at all. You could do it when you use lead-time or compile time weaving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved my 2 problems this way: created another `@Service` class and moved `method_B()` into it. I've annotated this class as `@Transactional`. Now the method `method_A()` looks like this:

```
public void method_A() {
   for(...) {
      ...
      try {
         anotherService.method_B();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         logger.error(...);
      }
   }
}
```

If `RuntimeException` occurs in the `method_B()` method, the exception is propertly logged, transaction of `method_B()` is rollbacked and the loop continuous. Thanks everybody for responses.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of throwing exceptions do the following. (return error code).

**Update:** I read your question after posting. if you call method_b from method_A both are under same transaction. Unfortunately you cannot rollback the method_b changes alone. Spring considers it as one transaction if they are all under one service class. (all methods).

One thing you can try is the following.

```
request to--> Controller() ---> (spring opens transaction) service_method_a(); (spring closes transaction) 
               Controller() ---> (spring opens transaction) service_method_c(); (spring closes transaction)  
               Controller() ---> (spring opens transaction) service_method_b(); (spring closes transaction) 
return <--
```

I hope it makes sense

Each of your methods a,b,c throw exceptions if it likes to be rolledback.

**Update:**
another approach. This one is much better.

If each of your method are in a different service then you can use the following annotations of the spring to run each of the method in a different transaction boundaries

```
p v serviceA{

   @transactional
   method_a(){
       serviceb.method_b();
   }

}

p v serviceB{

   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
   method_b(){

   }

}
```

more on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5539514/258741)

Spring transactional story [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) . Read the points below this article. Those are most important when developing the spring transactional app.

Comment: Zeus, thank you for your response, but `method_B()` would not be rollbacked in case of Exception, because you've surounded its body with try-catch block.

Comment: it's worth to try, thank you. Also, I want to ask about this your statement "if you call method_b from method_A both are under same transaction. Unfortunately you cannot rollback the method_b changes alone. Spring considers it as one transaction if they are all under one service class." If these methods are under the same transaction, so why can we add `@Transactional` annotation before method (not the class) with different parameters (propagation, isolation and etc.)? Is it because we want that transaction in different methods have to behave differently?

Comment: @polis I have updated the answer. Please refer to the link at the very end for the explanation of what I'm tryin to say. It is alread answered somewhere, so, i'm not taking pain in explaining it again.